# What PC software offers speeding up video & sound together at 20x+?

Tags: video-editor, webvideos

I'm new to video editing, and I'm trying to find the right software to fit my needs.  I am interesting in creating videos where I want to speed up both the video and the sound together to rates of over 20x.

For example, here is the link to a YouTube video that is similiar to the style movie that I want to make.  This person used iMovie to create [this video](https://youtu.be/DaxOfyn9Jls).

I started with the standard GoPro Studio, but whenever you speed up video with that program, the sound is lost.

I then moved to CyberLink Power Director, and with that program, the sound is not able to be sped up over 8x I believe when attached to the video.

I heard about Sony Video Studio, but it looks like you can't speed up the video past 4x in that program.

I do not want to break the sound apart from the video and try an pair it back up after speed up both the sound and video individually.  I also do not want to speed up the video/sound a small around, render the video, and then speed it up again, as that create a lot of redundant work.

Ideally, I would like to find the PC version of something like iMovie that has this capability.

Comment: Do you want the audio speedup to preserve pitch, or should a 100Hz sine wave in the input end up as a 2kHz sine wave in the output?  Or do you want a fast-forward type of sound where snippets of the input are sped up a bit?  (so you get a zip-zip-zip kind of sound.)  Most of these options should be doable with ffmpeg, but IDK about a GUI video NLE that includes that.

Comment: Speeding video and audio with ffmpeg easy. For audio you use rubberband filter multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I think Premiere can easily reach 80x. And you can go past that putting sequences one into the other

Answer (score 1):

- Import your file into a Premiere Pro project.
- Click right on the clip and select "New Sequence from Clip".
- The sequence is created.
- In that sequence, click right on the clip and choose "Speed" from the pop up menu.
- Adjust the speed percentage as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

DaVinci Resolve from BlackMagic Design can do this, and you could easily do it with the free version, which has very generous limitations.  If you decide to pay for the full version, it's a one-time fee, versus Adobe's perpetual subscription pricing.

Resolve is also fully cross-platform and supports Linux, where Premiere only runs on Mac and PC.

Resolve is an all-in-one postproduction suite.  Its functionality replaces not only Premiere, but also Prelude, After Effects, Lumetri/Speedgrade, Audition, and Adobe Media Encoder.

To speed up a video in Resolve:

•Command/Ctrl-I to import, select your video from the system dialogue.

•Drag the video from the media pool onto your timeline.

•Select the video on the timeline, and either use command/ctrl-D to change the entire Duration by a set amount, or use command/ctrl-R to Re-time ("speed ramp") variably.

Answer (score -1):

Almost every professional video suite can do it. Try premiere pro.